# Local EJB bean injection: unknown InjectionPoint of target EJB bean within injected EJB bean

Tags: logging, ejb-3.0, cdi

I have a special requirement: finding out the injection target EJB bean from the perspective of the injected EJB bean.

I've seen the concept of CDIs InjectionPoint and I need the same or a similar mechanism for local EJB injections.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/InjectionPoint.html

> Motivation:
>
> The class of the "final destination" should determined within the
>   @Produces CDI method to set an accurate logger category name.

A modular logging concept for an EAR application, consists of a modular server structure, might be realized this way.

I've no clue how to get some meta information from the EJB container where a local EJB bean is injected whenever it happened. Some kind of listener or event might help out, or is an interceptor or decorator approach the right path to find? Or do I get some information from the stack trace?

There are 2 beans with local interfaces in one EAR deployment.

Bean 1:

```
@Stateless
public class Bean1 implements Bean1_LocalInt {

  @Inject
  private Logger log;
  ...
}
```

Bean 2:

```
@Stateless
public class Bean2 implements Bean2_LocalInt {    

  @EJB 
  private Bean1_LocalInt bean1;

  ...
}
```

- CDI injection method "knows" Bean1 InjectionPoint
- Bean1 "know" Bean2 InjectionPoint -> unclear how to solve

Kind regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by using CDI with the producer pattern. The logger is set whenever a service SLSB will be injected.

If the SLSB is used in another target bean and the EJB container reuse the same instance of  an already created instance, will the injection be repeated and the producer method got passed again?

```
public class Resources {

@Inject 
@LocalService1
private LocalServiceInterface localService;

@Produces
@LocalService1
public LocalServiceInterface getLocalSTBServiceA(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {

    try {
        localEJBBean.setLogger(Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getBean().getBeanClass().getName()));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return localEJBBean;
  }
}
```

LocalServiceInterface:

```
@Local 
public interface LocalServiceInterface {
  public String getInfo();
  public void setLogger(Logger log);
}
```

The EJB :

```
@Stateless
public class LocalSTBServiceA implements LocalServiceInterface {

private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LocalSTBServiceA.class.getName());;

  public String getInfo() {
    log.info("test info for logger category test in LocalSTBServiceA.getInfo()");
    return "Hello Info!";
  }

  @Override
  public void setLogger(Logger log) {
    this.log = log;

  }
}
```

The target EJB injection class:

```
@Stateless
public class MemberRegistration {

    @Inject @LocalService1
    private LocalServiceInterface localService;

...
}
```